# mongodb update field of sharded collection using compass

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I am trying update one of the field in my mongo collection using mongodb compass.

Since my collection is shared, I am getting the below error

```
Query For shared findAndModify Must contain the Sharded key
```

So it possible update shared collection using mongodb compass

Comment: What is your shard key? You need to use for filtering condition shardkey(s) `db.collection.findAndModify({shard-key},{update})`. Take a look [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#sharded-collections)

Comment: I can run this commands from mongo client command line but How to run this from mongodb compass UI ?

Comment: What command was run in the shell?